# Tabitems issues in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

i have this simple tab control

```
            <TabControl Margin="0,32,0,0" Background="Aqua">

                <TabItem Header="Dashaboard"
                         FontSize="12"
                         Background="SaddleBrown"
                         Margin="-2,-2,-124,-21">
                    <local:Dashboard Margin="0,0,-8,0"
                                    />

                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Transfer Wizard"
                         Background="LightGray"
                         FontSize="15"
                         ToolTip="Transfering equipments between departments"
                         Margin="123,-2,-224,-21">
                    <local:TransferWizard Margin="0,-4,0,4"
                                          />

                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Addition Wizard"
                         Background="#c8f7c5"
                         ToolTip="Tab for equipment , customer and employees addition"
                         Margin="223,-2,-359,-21">
                    <local:EquipmentAddNavigator Margin="0,-23,0,0" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Addition Wizard"
                         Background="#c8f7c5"
                         ToolTip="Tab for equipment , customer and employees addition"
                         Margin="359,0,-526,-20">
                    <local:EquipmentAddNavigator Margin="0,-23,0,0"
                                                 Loaded="EquipmentAddNavigator_Loaded" />
                </TabItem>


            </TabControl>
```

and i have in Dashboard a method called ( refresh() )

here is my issues

1 how i can execute the refresh method whenever the user clicks on Dashboard tab item ?

2 how to define a global variable and make it accesible for all of tab items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle `Selector.Selected` event for `Dashboard TabItem` like this:

```
<TabItem Header="Dashaboard"
   FontSize="12"
   Background="SaddleBrown"
   Margin="-2,-2,-124,-21"
   Selector.Selected="Dashaboard_Selected">
   <local:Dashboard x:Name="Dashboard" Margin="0,0,-8,0"/>
</TabItem>
```

And in code:

```
private void Dashaboard_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      this.Dashboard.refresh()
}
```

And define your global variable in the class that your `TabControl` is in it.
For example if your `TabControl` is in `MainWindow.xaml` add a variable is `MainWindow` class like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private variable_type variable_name;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts , appreciated . one other question how i can pass that global variables to the other classes ?

Comment: You can make it `public static` or `internal static` variable or send it as a method argument to others.

Comment: Also you can define a static function that return this variable and keep it `private static`